# psql: how to explicitly tell port no

Tags: postgresql

I have installed postgresql and in postgresql.conf I see that port is 5433 instead of 5432.
Now when I try to connect to server through psql, I get error as:

> psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>
> (0x0000274D/10061)
>
> ```
>    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>
>    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> ```
>
> could not connect to server: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
>
> ```
>    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>
>    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
> ```

So can I tell in command to connect to port 5433?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Its:

```
psql -U postgres -p 5433
```